# Web application for browsing source code repositories

Tags: version-control, web-applications

Are there any web applications for browsing source code repositories that use popular version control systems?

I know that many open-source code sites have a web application for browsing code *on that site*, but are there any that let you view repositories hosted *on any site*? Sometimes, a web application is just so much more convenient than the alternatives.

Comment: Could you be more specific about which version control systems you want to access? There are web apps for each of the systems, but none that access all of them.

Comment: @Joeri: Mainly interested in the major ones: Subversion, Mecurial, Git, ect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [Fisheye](http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/) which is not open source, but it supports major VCS-s.

Comment: They have a 10 users for $10 offer, which is quite nice

Answer (score 1):

Or [websvn](http://www.websvn.info/) as an open source alternative to [FishEye](http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/) for subversion.